# RoR routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have placed my css in stylesheets folder and image in images folder. Both of these folders are in public folder of my rails application. However, I keep getting these errors:

```
Started GET "/assets/blueprint/print.css" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Nov 12 07:36:49 -0500 2011
Served asset /blueprint/print.css - 404 Not Found (2ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/blueprint/print.css"):


Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.3ms)


Started GET "/assets/custom.css" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Nov 12 07:36:49 -0500 2011
Served asset /custom.css - 404 Not Found (2ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/custom.css"):


Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.4ms)


Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Nov 12 07:36:49 -0500 2011
Served asset /logo.png - 404 Not Found (3ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/logo.png"):
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using 3.1. Try putting your stylesheet and js files under the assets directory. see the section on how to use the asset pipeline [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It's working now, but this is getting logged in the console: "Served asset /custom.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)". Is 304 some sort of error or is this normal? Thanks again.

Comment: This is nothing to worry about - it just means the resource didn't change since it was last served - see http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E304.html

Comment: It is just an information that the resource has not changed, so the cache could be used (see [HTTP Status Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and search there for 304.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue trying to get the correct assets to be included, but I was using 
Rails 3.2.6. This worked for me:

```
gem install sprockets
```

and then

```
bundle install
```

source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline